# Multiple EF issues. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: entity-framework, odp.net, odac

All,

I have the following connection string in an app.config file in a class-library project:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add 
      name="MyConnection"
      connectionString="
         metadata=res://*/Namespace.Model1.csdl|res://*/Namespace.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Namespace.Model1.msl;
         provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
         provider connection string='data source=&quot;
         (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myhost.mydomain.com)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = myservice.mydomain.com)(SERVICE = DEDICATED)))
         &quot;;
         password=MyPasswd;
         persist security info=True;
         user id=MyID'" 
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

As you can see, I'm using ODAC to connect to an Oracle server.  Everything seems to work fine, and I can update my model (EntityFramework) from my database.

However, when running the following code:

```
public class MyClass //classy, isn't it
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        MyCollectionEF = new MyCollection();
    }
    private MyCollection _MyCollectionEF;

    public MyCollection MyCollectionEF
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyCollectionEF;
        }
        set
        {
            _MyCollectionEF = value;
            _Region = (ICollection<RegionEnt>)_MyCollectionEF.RegionEnt.OrderBy(a => a.REGION);
            _LangSource = (ICollection<LangEnt>)_MyCollectionEF.LangEnt.OrderBy(a => a.LANGUAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

I end up with an "UnintentionalCodeFirst" Exception.  Okay, so clearly I'm probably doing something wrong at this point, but I persist and remove the throw exception from the OnModelCreating initializer (probably a bad idea, but I'm still new to this).

Next, I end up with a ModelValidationException stating that none of my entities have any keys (though when I look at the model, I can clearly see the keys involved).

Finally, after doing some digging, I find that when after initializing my _MyCollectionEF variable, the connection string magically changes to "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyConnection;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFrameworkMUE"

Okay, so now for questions (and I have a lot of them, unfortunately).

1) Why am I getting the UnintentionalCodeFirst Exception.  Is there a better way to load the data that I need into iCollections objects (or other objects suitable for data binding, adding, and removing data using MVVM pattern).

2) Why does the ModelValidationException get raised when clearly there are keys in my model, and what's the best way to get around this (keeping in mind that I plan to use MVVM).

3) Why is my ConnectionString magically changing?  Is this something that ODAC does behind the scenes, or is there a better reason.  I should point out that when doing _MyCollectionEF.DataBase.Connection.Open(), I get an error stating that the connection is refused for user "mywindowslogon", which makes sense because the actual server on the back-end is not setup for integrated security.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

EDIT: I should also point out that due to certain business requirements, parts of this are many:many relationship (i.e. in this simple example one region can have multiple languages and one language can have multiple regions).

EDIT: Also asked on social.msdn.microsoft.com

Comment: 2) I don't see any key properties on the MyClass class. 3) I don't see how you initialize your context and how you pass your connection string

Comment: _when running the following code_ That is a class definition that in itself does not run. So it is hard to tell where the exception is thrown. Further, "smart" property setters (`MyCollectionEF`) are an anti-pattern but in EF entities can really disrupt things (like triggering a read when an object is materialized). Finally if you want to work code-first from an existing data model use [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d).